# PHP/SQL: Installation queries in php or in sql

Tags: php, sql

Today I began rewriting my own simple CMS to the third version. In the first and the second version I had all queries written in simple sql files where one line was a comment and in following line was own query - and then again and again.

For example:

```
# pages names and other basic info
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pages_Base ( Number smallint(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Page_ID varchar(512) NOT NULL, Name varchar(50) NOT NULL, ContentType text NOT NULL, MenuOrder smallint(3) NOT NULL, MenuLevel text NOT NULL ) CHARACTER SET `latin2` COLLATE `latin2_czech_cs`;
```

I am not sure if it would not be better to rewrite all queries directly into install process - instead of having it in that sql file.

I know that some forums (for example phpBB or SMF) have those queries written directly in php, but still I am not sure what way to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still keep the queries in .sql file and just read the file and send it to the database during installation process?

That way you avoid telling users to import .sql file, but still all your queries are in .sql file for easy maintenance. It would be very easy to ignore empty lines and lines starting with # in php.