# SQL syntax coloring for Eclipse Kepler

Tags: sql, eclipse

Is anything (else) for Eclipse Kepler that colors SQL syntax ... and assists with SQL code editing? I don't anything more.

I tried DTP (Data Tools Platform), but it runs only with new files. It does not color syntax in already written files - and it is very bad, uncomfortable - because I have prepared few files and it is fully useless to create new file and copy (rewrite) content of original file into that new file, mostly if content assist does not assist with some *commands*.

Comment: I think there's no reason to tag SQL?

Comment: @user2841280: It is a better readable, if it is coloured. See [PHP/SQL: Installation queries in php or in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026322/php-sql-installation-queries-in-php-or-in-sql) to see form of my base queries. Then you would see that one line queries (even if there are capitalized basic words) may be quite not well readable if they are not coloured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From me I recommend Toad Extension for Eclipse. It does color syntax also in already written files.

Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software -> download from site: http://community-downloads.quest.com/toadsoft/toadextensions/eclipse/freeware/

Comment: I found that for getting coloured already written sql files may be used Open with ... Then he begin to colour code too. But thanks, and by the way, could you link to me some pages about TOAD? That link you wrote may be good - but I rather to read about it before any installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting syntax coloring in some files but not in others with the same extension, some of the files may have been opened with another editor previously and Eclipse remembers which editor was last used with a particular file. To change the editor that's used, right click on the file and select "Open With" option.

Comment: +1 With Data Platform Tools installed i had to right click the file in Project Explorer and choose Open With -> Sql File Editor to get syntax highlighting